# Biblatex-chicago @incollection: showing the volume field for articles in multivolume work

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

Using `biblatex-chicago`, how can I make sure that the `volume` field of an `@incollection` entry is printed in the first citation?

My entry looks something like this:

```
@incollection{ei2:ibn.al.haytham:vernet,
    Author = {Vernet, J.},
    Pages = {788--9},
    Title = {Ibn al-Haytham},
    Volume = {3},
    Xref = {ei2},
    Year = {1971}}

@book{ei2,
    Address = {Leiden},
    Edition = {2},
    Publisher = {Brill},
    Shorthand = {EI2},
    Title = {Encyclopaedia of Islam},
    Volumes = {12},
    Year = {1960--2005}}
```

I'd like the first `\cite{ei2:ibn.al.haytham:vernet}` command (assuming `ei2` has already been cited somewhere above) to output:

> J. Vernet, “Ibn al-Haytham,” in EI2, vol. 3, pp. 788–9

or even (but this is perhaps getting too ambitious)

> J. Vernet, “Ibn al-Haytham,” in EI2, vol. 3 (1971), pp. 788–9

Currently what I get is:

> J. Vernet, “Ibn al-Haytham,” in EI2, 788–9

which is not good, since it ignores the volume number.

I call `biblatex-chicago` in my preamble like this:

```
\usepackage[notes,
    backend=biber,
    mincrossrefs= 1,
    noibid,
    doi= false,
    eprint= false,
    url= false,
    usetranslator= true,
    abbreviate= true,
    uniquename= true
]{biblatex-chicago}
```

### MWE

#### test.tex

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,article,oneside,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{classics}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}


\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Palatino}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.80,Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.70,Ligatures=NoCommon]{Courier New}


\usepackage[    notes,
        backend=biber,
        mincrossrefs = 1,
        noibid,
        doi=        false,
        eprint=     false,
        url=        false,
        usetranslator=  true,
        abbreviate= true,
        uniquename= true
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\begin{document}

First time citation: \cite{ei2:ibn.al.haytham:vernet}


Second time citation (of a different article in the same book): \cite{ei2:tabari:bosworth}

\end{document}
```

#### test.bib

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/


%% Created for Alex at 2014-01-28 21:28:36 +0200 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@book{ei2,
    Abstract = {I:  1960
V:  1986},
    Address = {Leiden},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-28 19:28:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-28 19:28:22 +0000},
    Edition = {2},
    Publisher = {Brill},
    Shorthand = {EI2},
    Title = {Encyclopaedia of Islam},
    Year = {1960--2005}}

@incollection{ei2:ibn.al.haytham:vernet,
    Author = {Vernet, J.},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-28 19:28:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-28 19:28:22 +0000},
    Notetoself = {III (1971) 788--9},
    Pages = {788--9},
    Title = {Ibn al-Haytham, Abū ʿAlī…},
    Volume = {3},
    Xref = {ei2},
    Year = {1971}}

@incollection{ei2:tabari:bosworth,
    Author = {Bosworth, C. E.},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-28 19:28:22 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-28 19:28:22 +0000},
    Keywords = {Tabari},
    Pages = {11--15},
    Shorttitle = {al-Ṭabarī},
    Title = {al-Ṭabarī, Abū DJafar Muḥammad b.\ DJarīr b.\ Yazīd},
    Volume = {10},
    Xref = {ei2},
    Year = {2000}}
```

#### The output I get

> First time citation: J. Vernet, “Ibn al-Haytham, Abū ʿAlī...,” in
>   *Encyclopaedia of Islam*, 2nd ed., vol. 3 (Leiden: Brill, 1960–2005), 788–9, (hereafter cited as EI2).
>
> Second time citation (of a different article in the same book): C. E.
>   Bosworth, “al-Ṭabarī, Abū DJafar Muḥammad b. DJarīr b. Yazīd,” in EI2.

#### What I'd like to get

> First time citation: J. Vernet, “Ibn al-Haytham, Abū ʿAlī...,” in
>   *Encyclopaedia of Islam*, 2nd ed. (Leiden: Brill, 1960–2005) (hereafter cited as EI2), vol. 3 (1971), 788–9.
>
> Second time citation (of a different article in the same book): C. E.
>   Bosworth, “al-Ṭabarī, Abū DJafar Muḥammad b. DJarīr b. Yazīd,” in EI2, vol. 10 (2000), 11–15.

Or something like that. What I'm most interested in is being able to depend on the volume number appearing in the citation even when I use a normal `\cite` command and not `\volcite`.

(But as one reader kindly pointed out, it may be a problem with my software versions, since I have not updated yet to TeXLive 2013.)

### Update: new MWE with TeXLive 2013

Now I've updated to TeXLive 2013 (and updated all packages using TeX Live Utility). The situation is different, but not resolved. I used precisely the same MWE as above, except that I added
    \printshorthands
    \printbibliography
to `test.tex` right before `\end{document}`.

Now, curiously, the "shorthand" I defined for `ei2` (`Shorthand = {EI2}`) is ignored for the inline citations...

[image: MWE output using TeXLive 2013]

Comment: What version of `biblatex`/`biblatex-chicago` are you running (it's `2.8`/`0.9.9d` over here)? I get the output "J. Vernet, ‘Ibn al-Haytham’, in Encyclopaedia of Islam, 3:788–9" if EI2 was cited before, and "J. Vernet, ‘Ibn al-Haytham’, vol. 3 (1971), 788–9" if it was not (I do realise though that neither of those outputs is what you want). Also it would be really helpful if you could provide a full (compilable) MWE.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how can I check what version of `biblatex-chicago` I'm using? In any case, that may well be the problem, since I haven't yet updated to TeXLive 2013. (I hesitate because almost everything is working so well, so I'm afraid to change things, but I should probably move on.) Meanwhile, I've put together a full MWE, in case that is of help (I'll post it in a moment).

Comment: The question is not dumb at all. Version `0.9.9d (beta)` is what the documentation on my machine says on the title page (you can find it in the `doc\latex\biblatex-chicago` folder, the `README` in the folder also identifies the version as `version 0.9.9d, 2013-10-30`). In `biblatex-chicago.style` we find `biblatex-chicago.sty,v 0.1.1.53 2013/10/29 14:10:24`, while in `chicago-notes.bbx` it's `v 0.9.7.50 2013/10/29 12:32:21`. An update on your part might help us provide a solution we know works (we can test it) even if it does not resolve the problem in itself.

Comment: Now that I have updated to 2013, my version is also `0.9.9d (beta)`. As I have continued to work, I have noticed that in this new version, it consistently renders my bibtex entries which make use of the `xref` field incorrectly. Reading through the new documentation (`biblatex-chicago.pdf` §10, p.127), I am wondering if this new problem is due to changes made to the package (which have the result of not using the `xref`ed entry's `Title` field as the `@incollection`'s `Booktitle`). I have played around with the two new options `booklongxref` and `longcrossref`, with no success so far.

Comment: `biblatex-chicago.pdf`, p.84: "Please also note that the combination of `shorthand`, `reprinttitle`, and/or `userf` fields with shortened cross references may produce unexpected results, at least as `biblatex-chicago-authordate` currently stands. I advise caution before doing so." I'm not using `authordate`, but could this nevertheless explain the problem, since I *am* using `xref` and `shorthand` at the same time? It used to work so well, with only a few minor quirks (my original question in this post was about one of these quirks, namely a problem with how the `volume` field was treated).

Comment: I'm really not sure. The relevant code is really quite full-on and complicated. Maybe you would like to contact the author directly, since the current behaviour does seem like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe, for looking into it -- and I'm glad you agree that it seems like a bug. I've written to the author, so we'll see what he says.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a *partial* answer to the question, which I owe to the author of `biblatex-chicago`, David Fussner.
It is partial because my question ended up being about two separate issues:

1. a problem using `Shorthand` with volume numbers and `xref`
2. a problem with `@incollection` entries `xref`'d to `@book` entries in the new version of TeXLive (2013).

This is an answer to #2. To fix #2, I changed all `xref` entries to `crossref` entries. That still didn't quite work, since `@incollection` entries were not inheriting a `@book`'s `title` as a `booktitle` field, which is necessary to make the first citation of the `@incollection` entry appear with its book's title. For that, David Fussner provided me the following code, which he tells me may be incorporated into the next release of `biblatex-chicago`:

```
\DeclareDataInheritance{book}{incollection}{%
  \inherit{title}{booktitle}
  \inherit{subtitle}{booksubtitle}
  \inherit{titleaddon}{booktitleaddon}
  \noinherit{shorttitle}
  \noinherit{sorttitle}
  \noinherit{indextitle}
  \noinherit{indexsorttitle}
}
```

With this in the preamble, running TeXLive 2013, and using `crossref` (not `xref`) fields, my citations come out looking great. This solution even improves the situation with part #1 of my question, because now `@incollection` entries in multivolume books are printing their `volume` field on the first citation. What hasn't been quite resolved is how the `shorthand` with `crossref` works, since now the first time an article in the book is cited, the book's whole title appears, but *without* the phrase "hereafter cited as..."; the good news is that further citations of articles from the book use the book's `shorthand`!